# python ggplot not showing up using g.make()

Tags: python, ggplot2

Trying to show scatter using ggplot in python the code is

```
g = ggplot.ggplot(averaged ,aes(x = 'year', y = 'comb08_mean')) + ggplot.geom_point(color = 'steelblue') + ggplot.xlab('Year') + ggplot.ylab('Averaged MPG') + ggplot.ggtitle('All Cars')
g.make()
```

getting 
*TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index*

Answer (score 0):

I use `ggplot` with R, not python, but the issue may be a result of passing characters to `aes()`.  `ggplot` is setup to receive the named objects, not the names *of the objects*.  In R, if you type `df` into the console, the *object* is returned, whereas if you send the character vector `"df"`, that character vector `"df"` is returned.  It's probably the same case here using the python calls.

So change this term and see if that fixes it:

```
ggplot.ggplot(averaged ,aes(x = year, y = comb08_mean))
```

Guessing that "year" and "comb08_mean" are columns in your dataframe, `averaged`, right?

Comment: Yes, these are the columns.

Comment: No, It's not working. Now it is considering year and comb08_mean as a variable and the error is
NameError: name 'year' is not defined